# unable to vagrant ssh to windows box

Tags: ssh, vagrant, vagrant-windows

I downloaded windows 2012 box using vagrant. While doing a **vagrant up**, though the box was successfully installed on the virtual box,

[image]

It gave me the following error

[image]

Is there any config change, that needs to be done for windows box ?

Comment: What version of Vagrant?

Comment: @MattSchuchard - The version of vagrant is 1.9.7